# SSLConduit after exception on handshake: java.io.IOException: overflow

Tags: java, lets-encrypt, wildfly-18

Good day.
There is a legacy application for wildfly-18 and a Let's Encrypt certificate, it worked fine all the time, but after a short time it began to break with the error:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-48) Closing SSLConduit after handshake exception: java.io.IOException: overflow
at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doWrap(SslConduit.java:911)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doHandshake(SslConduit.java:649)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.access$900(SslConduit.java:63)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$5$1.run(SslConduit.java:1084)
at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.3.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.safeRun(WorkerThread.java:612)
at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.7.3.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:479)
```

The error is not googleable, maybe someone knows what the problem could be?